# Baire class 1 function

Tags: functional-analysis, baire-category

Let $(X,d)$ a complete metric space, $f_n : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a sequence of continuous functions and $f$ its pointwise limit.
Prove that:
a) exists an open dense set $W$ such that $f$ is locally bounded in $W$.
b) the set where $f$ is continuous is a $G_\delta$ in $X$.

I think $W$ should be define this way (for part a) ) $W=\bigcup_{k\ge 1} int(\bigcap_{n \ge 1} \left \{\mid f_n\mid\le k \right \}) $, but I'm not sure how to prove it's dense.
Any help? Thanks

Comment: For (a), (assuming $X$ not empty), prove that $W$ is open and not empty. Then if $Y$  is a non-empty open subspace of $X$ then $Y$ is completely metrizable and $f_n|_Y$ converges to $f|_Y,$ so there is a non-empty open $W_Y\subset Y$ on which $f|_Y$ is locally bounded. Therefore $f$ is locally bounded on the dense open set $\cup W_Y$, with the union over non-empty open $Y\subset X.$